# Can not get which dynamically added button is clicked in webforms in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have dynamically added delete button to each table row. The data of row are from database and each row has Id. So I added the Id as commandArguments in each button. But in the eventHandler method I can't typecast sender to button type.
As far I understand when a delete button is clicked sender is in .aspx format which can not be typecast to button. Now what can be the solution here ?

Here is the code that adds button to each row. This code is written inside Page_Load Sub of Default.aspx.vb

```
Dim cell6 As TableCell = New TableCell()
Dim deleteButton As Button = New Button()
deleteButton.Text = "Delete"
deleteButton.CommandArgument = rd(0)
deleteButton.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
AddHandler deleteButton.Click, AddressOf deleteButton_Click
cell6.Controls.Add(deleteButton)
```

And here is my eventHandler

```
Protected Sub deleteButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim bt As Button  = CType(sender,Button)
        Dim rowIndex As Int64 = bt.CommandArgument 

        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Try
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbConn").ConnectionString
            con.Open()
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = "Delete From dbo.Person where Id = @rowId"
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@rowId", rowIndex))
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception

        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try

        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
    End Sub
```

In this method `Dim bt As Button  = Ctype(sender,Button)` throws an exception. The exception is

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.default_aspx' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'.'
```

Comment: How you create + display that table? Best to use gridviewe, or even better use listview. That way you can include the button for each row as part of the markup. Using code to add a button in most cases means that the event wire up of that button cannot occur at runtime. However, you have to share if you using listview, gridview to display this data (and if not - then why?). But you as a general rule have to wire up run-time added buttons with JavaScript to do a postback with some values. The code behind is resolved at compile time - not at runtime. But, all of your grid choices allow buttions.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use tags when trying to do this.

When creating the button...

```
deletebutton.tag="yourID"
```

Then in the handler I can just call

```
yourID=sender.tag
```